# How to share device gallery or captured images in social media like Facebook, watsapp by using titanium studio?

Tags: titanium, titanium-android

I want to share device gallery images to social media like (Facebook, WhatsApp, Twitter, Google+) by using Titanium Studio.

I have a button to capture the images.  When image is captured i want to share that image through device supported sharing applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use built-in modules like Facebook. See more in [Appcelerator documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook)
2. Use some of the modules created by others, e.g. [social.napp.dk](http://gitt.io/component/dk.napp.social) - you can also browse/search for more options on [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/search?q=social) :-)

/John